# Algorithm for smooth exponential curves

Tags: algorithms, exponential-function, exponential-sum

I want to plot an exponential curve between 256 and 0. Using the following equasion, I get the resulting data set. *(Please note that I am rounding any decimals down to nearest whole number throughout this question)*

**Equasion**

```
x = x / 2;
```

**Data**

```
256, 128, 64, 32, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1, 0
```

**Curve**

[image]

The algorithm above took 10 iterations before it reached 0 (since there are 10 values in the data set).

Say for example, I know how many iterations should occur, is there a way to work out the number that x should be divided by, given the number of iterations?

**Example**

I want to generate a smoother curve, still based on the values 256 and 0, but it should appear smoother because there are more points in the data set.

**Equasion**

```
x = x / 1.2
```

**Data**

```
256, 213, 177, 147, 122, 101, 84, 70, 58, 48, 40, 33, 27, 22, 18, 15, 12, 10, 8, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0
```

**Curve**

[image]

In this example, the curve is much smoother because there are more data points to plot it.

Say for example, the only thing I knew about this example was

- The maximum and minimum numbers
- There **must** be 26 iterations

How do I work out what x must be divided by to get the target iteration count?

```
x = x / ???
```

Comment: To be clear, do you want the continuous approximation or rounding at each step. I assume the latter? If rounding, you really want always rounding down? (That's ok, but a bit odd)?

Answer (score 0):

It is approximately $256^{1/n}$ where $n$ is the number of iterations, and suppose $256$ is your upper bound.